# How to transfer Oracle (+) operator with joins to Spark SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, apache-spark

I have a part of code in Oracle as this:

```
SELECT 
      t1.col1,
      t1.col2,
      t2.col1,
      t2,col2
FROM 
      t1,
      t2   
WHERE 
      t1.col1           <> 121 
      AND t1.col1       =  t2.col1(+)
      AND t1.col2       =  t2.col2(+)
      AND 'ABC'         =  t2.col3(+)
```

How to transfer it to Spark SQL assuming tables (t1 and t2) are already registered?

Thanks.

Comment: . . An outer join makes no sense because you are only selecting columns from the first table.  Just remove the second table and all references to it.

Comment: Wow... Oracle syntax from the 80's.

Comment: Adjusted Select statement.. Still need to perform join.. (initially removed it from Select statement to make it easier to show the SQL but not trying to improve the query logically - trying to translate Oracle 80's style to modern Spark SQL).. There are several queries that I need to do that have similar things so trying to learn here..

Comment: If you could explain what you're trying to achieve with some input example you'll get better/faster help, as not everyone (including me) is familiar with that specific Oracle syntax...

Comment: I got legacy code in Oracle and need to transfer to Spark SQL. That is all I know - no knowledge/information is available on why etc. Just need to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(+)` is the *old* Oracle outer join operator. It was used like this (Scott's sample schema; there are no employees in department 40 so - if you want to display it, you have to use outer join):

```
SQL> select d.deptno, d.dname, e.ename
  2  from emp e,
  3       dept d
  4  where d.deptno = e.deptno (+)        --> outer join
  5  order by d.deptno, e.ename;

    DEPTNO DNAME          ENAME
---------- -------------- ----------
        10 ACCOUNTING     CLARK
        10 ACCOUNTING     KING
        10 ACCOUNTING     MILLER
        20 RESEARCH       ADAMS
        20 RESEARCH       FORD
        20 RESEARCH       JONES
        20 RESEARCH       SCOTT
        20 RESEARCH       SMITH
        30 SALES          ALLEN
        30 SALES          BLAKE
        30 SALES          JAMES
        30 SALES          MARTIN
        30 SALES          TURNER
        30 SALES          WARD
        40 OPERATIONS                         --> department with no employees

15 rows selected.
```

If Spark SQL supports modern ANSI syntax, then the above code can be rewritten to

```
SQL> select d.deptno, d.dname, e.ename
  2  from dept d left join emp e on e.deptno = d.deptno        --> outer join
  3  order by d.deptno, e.ename;

    DEPTNO DNAME          ENAME
---------- -------------- ----------
        10 ACCOUNTING     CLARK
        10 ACCOUNTING     KING
        10 ACCOUNTING     MILLER
        20 RESEARCH       ADAMS
        20 RESEARCH       FORD
        20 RESEARCH       JONES
        20 RESEARCH       SCOTT
        20 RESEARCH       SMITH
        30 SALES          ALLEN
        30 SALES          BLAKE
        30 SALES          JAMES
        30 SALES          MARTIN
        30 SALES          TURNER
        30 SALES          WARD
        40 OPERATIONS                      --> department with no employees

15 rows selected.

SQL>
```

See if it helps.

Answer (score -1):

I do not see the point of joining t1 and t2:

```
SELECT 
  t1.col1,
  t1.col2
FROM 
  t1
WHERE 
  t1.col1 <> 121
```